# Consulta de dados arquivo settings

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho alguns projetos na minha solution e em um deles vou ter o settings configurado com alguns parâmetros.

A minha dúvida é: Se referenciado esse projeto nos outros, consigo ler esses parâmetros em cada projeto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem, basicamente, duas opções:

- Se quiser expor **todas** propriedades definidas no `settings`, você pode alterar o modificador da classe `Settings` de `internal` para `public`
- Se **não** quiser expor **todas** propriedades definidas no `settings`, você pode criar uma classe para implementar encapsulamento. Ex:

  ```
  public class AcessoAoSettings 
  {
      public Propriedade1 
      { 
          get 
          {
              return Properties.Settings.Default.Propriedade1;
          }
          set
          {
              Properties.Settings.Default.Propriedade1 = value;
          }
      }

      public Propriedade2 
      { 
          get 
          {
              return Properties.Settings.Default.Propriedade2;
          }
          private set;
      }
  }
  ```

---

Eu, particularmente, prefiro a segunda opção pois se quiser, você pode controlar o acesso de escrita (nesse código, a `Propriedade2` faz isso deixando o `set` como `private`).

Answer (score 1):

Você poderá utilizar o recurso **"Copy As Link"**.
No seu projeto B, vá na opção para adicionar um item existente, e escolha o arquivo de configuração do projeto A e adicione como um link. Veja as imagens:

[image: Add > Existing Item...]
[image: Add As Link]

[Veja também.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714082(v=vs.105).aspx)